# Test Learner widget's evaluation results don't update (Orange GUI)

Tags: orange

I am using the Rank widget to pick attributes which feed into a few classifiers and in turn feed into a test learner so I can check the performance by looking at the evaluation results.  (As per the attached screenshot)

Everything works except that the eval results don't update.  The data path is fine, for example my prediction vs actual scatter plots update and the "i'm reevaluation" spinners happen... but no new numbers.

I on mac using a recent download (2.7.8.dev-2576588) but the same is true (or at least sporadically true from my limited testing) on windows using the older version (2.7.8.dev-a6ac40a).

Is this affecting others?  I can't find any discussion about it which makes me think that I must be doing something wrong or using Orange incorrectly.

[image: screenshot of widgets and dialogs involved]

Answer (score 0):

You should be feeding the data from 'Rank' widget directly to the 'Test Learners' widget. The 'Data' input to the learners widget only affect it's 'Classifier' output (unfortunately however it does trigger an update downstream).